# Could not render the url. Could not get image from url.Navigation timeout

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, winnovative

I've got a ASP.NET web application which contains the `Winnovative HTML to PDF Converter`.

This has been running for over a year successfully generating PDFs

However, this is no longer working, and the error being returned is:

```
Could not render the url. Could not get image from url.Navigation timeout..
```

I've checked the [Winnovative FAQ](http://www.winnovative-software.com/FAQ.aspx) and they suggest adding a `NavigationTimeout` to the instance of the PdfConverter. I've added the following:

```
PdfConverter.NavigationTimeout = 500
```

However, this has not fixed the error. Furthermore, the page being converted only takes a fraction of a second to load when loading directly in the browser, so I don't believe its a performance issue with the page being rendered.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Are there any known solutions/causes for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I found out this error was occuring because we were trying to request a PDF from a HTTPS file.

I weren't able to solve why though.

Please see this question if you have an answer:

[Generating PDF from HTTPS causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673544/generating-pdf-from-https-causes-error)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I think in my case, it is a matter of large record sets and lengthy conversion process.

Comment: @Jeffrey I think I have the same problem... Is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets this error: In our case, running on IIS 8.5, changing the application pool from **ApplicationPoolIdentity** to **Network Service** fixed it.  So it seems it is a folder permission problem.  Network service isn't ideal and really the actual folder permissions should be set.