# Generating PDF from HTTPS causes error

Tags: asp.net, ssl, pdf-generation, winnovative

I'm using [Winnovative PDF Converter](http://www.winnovative-software.com) to generate PDF files from HTML (URL)

When triggering a button on a HTTP web page, to generate a PDF from a HTTP URL, this works fine.

However when triggering a button on a HTTPS web page, to generate a PDF from a HTTP URL, I get the error:

> Could not render the url. Could not get image from url.Navigation
>   timeout..

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

**Please Note:** I'm not getting an error when generating a PDF of a HTTPS page, I'm getting an error when making a web request from a HTTPS page to generate a PDF

Comment: I successfully created a PDF version of `https://www.google.com` from the live demo module they had given in their homepage. Maybe there is a certificate trust issue?

Comment: The Winnovative website isn't in SSL mode. I think you may have misunderstood my question. Generating a PDF from a HTTPS page works fine, its making a request from a HTTPS page to generate a PDF which returns the error. Sorry if I haven't made this clear

Comment: Just some ideas -- Does the same thing happen with different browsers?  Also does the page that you are generating have any cache directives that make it "private" or "no-cache" or expires immediately?  There are sometimes issues in IE, with files like PDF/Excel/SWF that are not to be cached over SSL.  Also if you're going from HTTPS to HTTP perhaps there is a "this page has secure and insecure content" issue.  Don't know how the winnovative tool works but does the same request work HTTPS->HTTPS?  It is just HTTPS->HTTP that errors out?

Comment: I had the same issue and I suspected the ssl as well. But it did work on another server with same ssl certificate. The only difference was the IE versions, since Winnovative uses IE, I uninstalled IE9 on the server which it was faulty and IT WORKED with IE8.